# jquery mmenu how to return to previous section by clicking some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

when i click a "img" ,I want to return to the  previous section .

```
img  id="myimg" onclick="pageback()"

function pageback() 
{  //do some thing here  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Also, add some more code to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function pageback() {
    //assuming names of section to be currentsection & previoussection
    currentsection.hide();
    previoussection.show();
}
```

Comment: I just find a rule  <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-highest mm-current mm-opened" id="mm-467"><div class="mm-navbar" style="height: 0px;"><a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#menupv" data-target="#menupv"></a><a class="mm-title" href="#menupv">Delivery area</a></div><ul class="mm-listview"><li><a class="mm-next mm-fullsubopen" href="#mm-468" data-target="#mm-468"></a><span>Malaysia</span></li></ul></div>     i used $('div.mm-current') can get the  currentsection,and the previoussection  is in the <a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#menupv" data-target="#menupv"></a>

Comment: but the <a class="mm-btn mm-prev" ></a>  is not the only one, how to get its href

Comment: @wjy : you can get it like this `$('a.mm-btn.mm-prev').attr('href')`

Comment: $('a.mm-btn.mm-prev').attr('href') can not find the one in the <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-highest mm-current mm-opened" ></div> ,  it is not the only one

Comment: @wjy: which anchor tag you want to select? You need to select only one or all of them ?

Comment: @wjy: Select like this: `$('div.mm-navbar').find('a.mm.prev').attr('href')` .

Comment: for example, you see <a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#menupv" data-target="#menupv"></a>  in the <div class="mm-panel mm-hasnavbar mm-highest mm-current mm-opened" id="mm-467"><div class="mm-navbar" style="height: 0px;"><a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#menupv" data-target="#menupv"></a>...........</div>,i  want get this <a>, but i can not use  $('a.mm-btn.mm-prev').attr('href'), because too many <a class="mm-btn mm-prev" href="#menupv" data-target="#menupv"></a> in the <body>

Comment: @wjy: select the one in the nav-bar div, I have given you the selector in previous comment. Select one parent div and then go for its child anchor tag.    Select like this: `$('div.mm-navbar').find('a.mm.prev').attr('href')`

Comment: @wjy: That's alright. You might want to learn about CSS selectors -https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors and jquery selectors - https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

For return to previous page use:

```
function pageback() 
{
  window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: that will be go back to previous page, not the previous section in mmenu

Comment: @Stan Zeez, Using window.history.back() or any browser function inside a client code is not recommended. Also, this function when called from the required page will do the needful. However, if it is called from third page it will take you back to the page you came from not the desired page, as is the case here. Correct me if I am wrong.